# How to remove undefined array using Javascript in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

The code below is generating dataLayer variables, but sometimes the "sourceTraffic" variable is undefined. I want it so that if any variable is undefined or null, it should not be visible.

I am new to JavaScript and have been trying things after reading posts and blogs. The below mentioned screen shot gives the idea how this is currently visible.

```
<script>

function cleanArray(actual){
var newArray = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i<actual.length; i++){
if (actual[i]){
newArray.push(actual[i]);
 }
}
 return newArray;
 }
 var temporary = {{sourceTraffic}}
 cleanArray([temporary]);

 <script>

 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
   dataLayer.push({

     'aNewDLV':'{{1Refferer}};{{Date Time of Browser}}:{{nPageName}}|      {{sourceTraffic}}'

 })
```

`

http://prntscr.com/8bv67r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably put in a check to see if the variable is defined or not, and if so, then include it in the push, otherwise don't include it:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
if (typeof temporary !== "undefined") {
   dataLayer.push({
      'aNewDLV':'{{1Refferer}};{{Date Time of Browser}}:{{nPageName}}|{{sourceTraffic}}'
   })
} 
else {
   dataLayer.push({
      'aNewDLV':'{{1Refferer}};{{Date Time of Browser}}:{{nPageName}}'
   })
}
```

You could follow the same methodology for other variables, too.